# Typing params with several middlewares | Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I'm using Typescript, and while I'm trying to type parameters in `Request`, I get an error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '(req: Request<IUpdateQA, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.       Type '(req: Request<IUpdateQA, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.         Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.           Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Request<IUpdateQA, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.             Types of property 'params' are incompatible.               Property 'id' is missing in type 'ParamsDictionary' but required in type 'IUpdateQA'.
```

My route:

```
QuestionAnswerRouter.delete('/:id', shopAuthMiddleware, QuestionAnswerController.delete );
```

My code (has error):

```
async delete(req: Request<{id: number}>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   ...
}
```

And when I'm trying this, it works (`Request` has no generic):

```
async delete(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Param type is always `string`.

```
export interface ParamsDictionary {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Try to replace `number` by `string` and the error should not longer appear.

```
async delete(req: Request<{id: string}>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   ...
}
```